# Changing Array Output with If Statements

Tags: php, html, arrays, api

I am new to API integration and PHP. I recently integrated a VIN decoder into my app. Enter a vehicle's VIN into the input box, select submit, and all information regarding that vehicle from the API's database is presented.

The data is stored as an associative array, with categories and their corresponding elements. For example for VIN: WAUBFAFL6FA058452 one of the categories is Make and its element is Audi.

Some VIN's carry more data with them than others. I only wanted the categories with data to show up upon selecting submit. So with some help, I added this line of code:

```
    foreach ($json['Results'][0] as $k => $v){
  if (!empty($v)) {
    $results .= ($k).": ".($v).'<br />';
    }
```

This is what an output looks like:

```
AirBagLocCurtain: All Rows
AirBagLocFront: 1st Row (Driver & Passenger)
AirBagLocSide: 1st Row (Driver & Passenger)
BodyClass: Sedan/Saloon
DisplacementCC: 1984
DisplacementCI: 121.071108283
DisplacementL: 1.984000
Doors: 4
EngineCylinders: 4
EngineHP: 220
EngineKW: 164.0540
EngineManufacturer: Audi
EngineModel: Flex Fuel Capable engine
ErrorCode: 0 - VIN decoded clean. Check Digit (9th position) is correct
FuelTypePrimary: Gasoline
FuelTypeSecondary: Ethanol (E85)
Make: AUDI
Manufacturer: AUDI
ManufacturerId: 1149
Model: A4
ModelYear: 2015
OtherEngineInfo: Fuel: Gas (50-St); Federal / California Emission Standard: BIN 5 / ULEV II; Emissions Certification Test Group: FVGAV02.0AUB / FVGAJ02.0AUF E85
PlantCity: Ingolstadt
PlantCountry: Germany
SeatBeltsAll: Manual
Series: Premium quattro
TPMS: Indirect
TransmissionStyle: Automatic
VIN: WAUBFAFL6FA058452
VehicleType: PASSENGER CAR
```

What I want to do next is edit the category name. For example: change ModelYear to Year, TransmissionStyle to Transmission Type, EngineHP to Horsepower, and so on. I tried adding a simple IF Statement with $k as the variable; however, this did not work. You will see this attempt in my PHP code below. Any ideas on how to edit category names?

Here is my html, it is a simple input bar and submit button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VIN Decoder API Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
input,button {width: 200px;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
button {width: 100px;background-color: darkgray;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="processvin3.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="b12" placeholder="Enter VIN" name="b12" maxlength="100"/>
    <br>
    <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>

  </form>

  <br>
  <br>

</body>
</html>
```

And my PHP

```
<?php

$vin = $_POST["b12"];

if ($vin) {
$postdata = http_build_query([
        'format' => 'json',
        'data' => $vin
    ]
);
$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $postdata
    ]
];

$apiURL = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/";
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($apiURL, 'rb', false, $context);
$line_of_text = fgets($fp);
$json = json_decode($line_of_text, true);
fclose($fp);

foreach ($json['Results'][0] as $k => $v){
  if (!empty($v)) {
    $results .= ($k).": ".($v).'<br />';
    }
    if ($k == "ModelYear"){
      $k  = "Year";
    }
  }

  echo $results;
  }

else {
echo 'No Vin Inputted';
  }

?>
```

Thanks so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Layout of API Data Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899222/changing-the-layout-of-api-data-output)

Comment: @Dave It is not.

Comment: Move `if` before `$results .= ...`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a lookup array versus a battery of conditionals.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vGWfv))

```
$json['Results'][0] = [
    'AirBagLocCurtain' => 'All Rows',
    'AirBagLocFront' => '1st Row (Driver & Passenger)',
    'AirBagLocSide' => '1st Row (Driver & Passenger)',
    'BodyClass' => 'Sedan/Saloon',
    'DisplacementCC' => '1984',
    'DisplacementCI' => '121.071108283',
    'DisplacementL' => '1.984000',
    'Doors' => '4',
    'EngineCylinders' => '4',
    'EngineHP' => '220',
    'EngineKW' => '164.0540',
    'EngineManufacturer' => 'Audi',
    'EngineModel' => 'Flex Fuel Capable engine',
    'ErrorCode' => '0 - VIN decoded clean. Check Digit (9th position) is correct',
    'FuelTypePrimary' => 'Gasoline',
    'FuelTypeSecondary' => 'Ethanol (E85)',
    'Make' => 'AUDI',
    'Manufacturer' => 'AUDI',
    'ManufacturerId' => '1149',
    'Model' => 'A4',
    'ModelYear' => '2015',
    'OtherEngineInfo' => 'Fuel: Gas (50-St); Federal / California Emission Standard: BIN 5 / ULEV II; Emissions Certification Test Group: FVGAV02.0AUB / FVGAJ02.0AUF E85',
    'PlantCity' => 'Ingolstadt',
    'PlantCountry' => 'Germany',
    'SeatBeltsAll' => 'Manual',
    'Series' => 'Premium quattro',
    'TPMS' => 'Indirect',
    'TransmissionStyle'=> 'Automatic',
    'VIN' => 'WAUBFAFL6FA058452',
    'VehicleType' => 'PASSENGER CAR'
];

$lookup = [
    'ModelYear' => 'Year',
    'TransmissionStyle' => 'Transmission Type',
    'EngineHP' => 'Horsepower'
];

foreach ($json['Results'][0] as $k => $v) {
    if (!empty($v)) {
        $result[] = (isset($lookup[$k]) ? $lookup[$k] : $k) . ": $v";
    }
}
// alphabetize new keys now with sort() if desired
echo implode("<br>", $result);
```

---

Now that I see [your new project requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51939116/2943403), an `if/elseif` block is better suited (because of the conditional `round()` call).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A7LTh))

```
foreach ($json['Results'][0] as $k => $v){
    if (strlen($v)) {  // only bother to process this element if it contains a value with a positive length
        if ($k == "DisplacementCC") {
            $results[]  = "Engine Displacement 2: $v cc's";
        } elseif ($k == "DisplacementCI") {
            $results[] = "Engine Displacement 3: $v ci's";
        } elseif ($k == "DisplacementL") {
            $results[] = "Engine Displacement 1: " . round($v, 1) . " liters";
        } elseif ($k == "EngineKW") {
            $results[] = "Kilowatts: $v kw";
        } elseif ($k == "EngineManufacturer") {
            $results[] = "Engine Manufacturer: $v";
        } elseif ($k == "EngineModel") {
            $results[] = "Engine Model: $v";
        } elseif ($k == "FuelTypePrimary") {
            $results[] = "Primary Fuel Type: $v";
        } elseif ($k == "FuelTypeSecondary") {
            $results[] = "Secondary Fuel Type: $v";
        } elseif ($k == "EngineHP") {
            $results[] = "Horsepower: $v hp";
        } elseif ($k == "EngineCylinders") {
            $results[] = "Engine Size: $v cylinders";
        }
    }
}

echo "<div id=\"VIN\">{$json['Results'][0]['VIN']}</div>";
echo "<div id=\"EngineDetails\">";
    echo "Engine-<br /><br />";
    echo implode("<br />", $results);
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. Why do you prefer the lookup over the conditionals?

Comment: It is easier to read and maintain... however, now that I see your new question for this project (specifically `round()`), you will be better to use an `if-elseif` block or `switch-case` block.  I'll offer an answer on your new question

Comment: @mugelloblue I have updated my answer considering your new question's details.  If you are satisfied, please accept my answer so that this question is deemed resolved.  (All of your questions should eventually receive a green tick'ed answer so that: 1. future readers can confidently learn from the best answer 2. Volunteers are rewarded for offering you support 3. So that the system knows this question is resolved.